# Calling a script snippet by id in a React SPA and content only loads on refresh

Tags: javascript, reactjs, one-trust

Working on a React application that makes use of a 3rd party JS script from OneTrust cookie scripts. Their scripts really are not designed well for SPAs. Right now I’m simply calling the script section by ID within a div and nothing else as the entire script is parked elsewhere within the project - nothing fancy there. I have a simple `CookiePolicy.jsx` component like below:

```
const CookiePolicy = () => {
    return <div id=“cookieHTMLSnippet” />
}
```

The snippet provides a load of text and some tables based on the HTML of the parent script. The parent script could be called something like `cookie-policy.js`

The issue is it only loads the content on page  reload. I don’t have much code to share but I can only think of doing something weird with `getElementById`, somehow connect some state to it and place it within a `useEffect` and force the content to load using `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`. Is there a simpler, more elegant way to approach this issue? I’m sure I’m not the only one struggling with 3rd party scripts in a SPA...

As a note, in this scenario changing the placement of the script or where I’m calling this ID itself is not an option.

Comment: Could you elaborate on *why* you can't just include the OneTrust script outside of the React app and in the, for example,`index.html` file?

Comment: It isn’t clear in your question what is the problem you’re trying to solve, and why is it not possible to just embed the script in the html page.

Comment: This project doesn’t make use of an index.html file, as a short answer

Comment: Uhh… there’s always an entry point. Otherwise how is the page being served?

Comment: The issue I am trying to solve is loading a 3rd party script in a React application without refreshing the page - due to the project not recognizing the script data until refresh. I cannot edit the index.html file so that is the whole reason I’m in this situation unfortunately

Comment: It’s a bit stickier even because SSR is in place for this project. That’s how we are serving

Comment: His problem is the third party script needs to load the content in a react container, but that script almost certainly hooks onto events like page load that are fired before the react app even loads.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the comments guys and appreciate the suggestion @adsy!

There was an exposed function(`initializeCookiePolicyHtml`) I missed the first time around that generates the HTML which made this much simpler.

Ended up implementing it like this:

````
  useEffect(() => {
    typeof window.OneTrust !== 'undefined' && window.OneTrust.initializeCookiePolicyHtml(true)
  }, [])
  return <div id="cookieHTMLSnippet" />
}```
````

Answer (score -1):

You can try synthetically triggering the events it listens to (I've made an educated guess below) -- but it's hacky and could well have a knock-on effect with other scripts that could be listening. If it's a script you don't control, check the dev docs thoroughly as often these things put a global function on `window` you can call to force it to check the DOM again. Sometimes it's undocumented. Check `window` in dev tools for anything populated by this script.

That would be preferable, but if not:

```
const CookiePolicy => {
    // Layout effect waits for DOM to render
    useLayoutEffect(() => {
          dispatchEvent(new Event('load'))
          dispatchEvent(new Event('DOMContentLoaded'))
    }, [])

    return (
        return <div id=“cookieHTMLSnippet” />
    );
}
```